# Installing node js on debian

Tags: debian, node.js

js on debian and got it working but I want to understanding what the command that their website recommends is actually doing.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Im pretty new to the linux world and am just wanting to know what each part of the commands are doing. Thanks

Also here is there page that shows the steps Im using

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl` is a tool for creating web requests.  This command downloads the file located at the [given URL](https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x) and then executes it as `sudo`.  That downloaded script takes care of downloading and installing the nodesource repository.

Normally this is a very dangerous command to run, since the script could do pretty much anything to your machine.  Its a good idea to either review the script in a web browser first or, just download the script and review it before running it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should really checkout [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which is a tool for installing and managing node versions.